# Leaving out names/pronouns to speed up the flow of a script?

Tags: formatting, screenwriting, description

Example: Jane digs in the flowerbed for her ring. Moves to the yard.

I’ve seen this a bunch of times, but it still feels sort of wrong when I do it. I just want to know if this  is “normal”.

Thanks!

Bonus question: are adverbs really so bad in screenplays?

Comment: I'm not sure what adverb rules you're referring to, but I'd suggest you forget them all and just use as many adverbs as necessary, but not more.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Write Right Now](http://www.writerightnow.co.uk/sentence-fragments-in-screenwriting-bending-the-rules-of-grammar/), using sentence fragments in scripts is standard.

> But take a look at any half-competent screenplay and you’ll find it full of clipped sentences, which still make sense. This is because screenwriting is about communicating a plan of action, a blueprint, not a full-bodied description or a fortress of flawless grammar.